# VBA - Moving TextBox in a userform

Tags: vba

I have 40 text boxes in userform but i use only first 7 to 8 textbox most of the time, is there any way if 8th or 9th textbox is empty then it can move to last textbox 40

Comment: is this in Excel?

Comment: Your question is unclear - what is "it" in " it can move to last textbox 40" ?

Comment: on pressing enter (without putting any value in textbox) next textboxes should be skipped and cursor should move to textbox40 (it will eliminated pressing enter key for rest of the textboes)

Comment: yes in excel, but using userform

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution could be if each text box contained default text that got deleted, which would trigger a TextBox#.Change routine. The Return Key will not trigger the Change routine and each of the 40 text boxes would require a TextBox#.Change routine.

With each text box set to Tab to the next, the user form EnterFieldBehavior property set to SelectAll, and default text such as "Enter" in each box ... tabbing selects the box's content and the Delete Key trigger the Change routine, which handles the rest of what you want to accomplish with the partially completed user form.